# Using VBA in Excel, how do I loop through a column and create new sheets based on cell values?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in sheet 1 containing different values. I'd like to loop thru the column and create new sheets with the sheet name corresponding to the values. Each time I create a sheet, I like to set the new sheet active and do some task on that sheet.

```
 Sub test()
 i = 4 'starting row in sheet 1

   While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = Cells(i, 1).Value
    'do something to new sheet

    i = i + 1
 Wend
 End Sub
```

This does not work and the examples I've found online are way too complex for my need. I hope for an easy solution pointing out what I did wrong. thanks

Comment: Your `Cells(i, 1)` does not specify the worksheet those cells are on; there's an implicit reference to the `ActiveSheet`. Specify the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

This adds worksheets and names them as per the values in A4 downwards:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim wksNew As Worksheet
Dim rngCell As Range

Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rngCell = wks.Range("A4")

While Not IsEmpty(rngCell)
    Set wksNew = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    wksNew.Name = rngCell.Value

    'do stuff with wksNew

    Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(1)
Wend
```